# How to disconnect a remote volume in dolphin

Tags: networking, kde, dolphin

I understand how I can mount a distant volume in Dolphin, through the `Network` place and the `Add Network Folder` command, but how can I disconnect from such a remote file system? I want to ensure a manual disconnect, not a mere timeout.

Comment: Would you please explain more....

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear enough, but can you be more specific about what you do not understand?

Comment: Off-topic, can't be reproduced??? You mean someone actually observed the closing of connections by Dolphin with Wireshark? In which version of Dolphin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dolphin does not seem to be able to use the disconnection methods of the various protocol it uses.

A KDE contributor [said on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6kz6wc/comment/djq0hex/?context=3) that the user isn't intended to disconnect manually.